# Show all files from directory beginning with newest file

Tags: php, file, directory

I am trying to show all my files in a directory beginning with newest file added in directory. Right now I can only include all the files with the following code.

```
<?php
foreach (glob("posts/*.php") as $filename)
{
include $filename;
}
?>
```

I also managed to include only the most recent file, but I cant seem to figure out how to do it all together. I would be happy for any help. Thanks

Comment: What's your code for the most recent file?

Comment: <?php
$ctime = 0;
foreach (glob('"posts/*.php") as $file)
{
if ($ctime > filectime($file))
{
$match = $file;
$ctime = filectime($file);
}
}

print $file;
?>

Answer (score 0):

First fill an array with information - filename and change date

```
$files = array();
foreach( glob( "posts/*.php" ) as $filename ) {
   $files[] = array(
     "name" => $filename,
     "change_date" => filectime( $filename );
   );
}
```

Then sort it by the change date

```
usort( $files, function($a, $b) {
   return $a->change_date - $b->change_date;
} );
```

And finally, do something with the sorted list

```
foreach ( $files as $file ) {
  echo $file;
}
```